# AJAX GET REQUEST WITH MULTIPLE PARAMETERS, ONE URL, RESULTS PUSHED INTO ARRAY

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, callback, get

I am using the Indeed job search API which only shows 25 results per GET request.
I need to make 4 GET requests to receive 100 search results, incrementing the &start= number by 25 in the query URL every time.

I can recieve the first set of 25 results just fine, but I want to add a loop that increments the search results by 25, 4 times. The problem is I don't know how to add a callback function that waits for the loop to run 4 times and then pushes ALL 100 results into a single array, and THEN returns the results.

Can anyone help? This is my non-working code.

I am using NODE, and AXIOS for the GET requests.

```
var axios = require("axios");

var emptyArray = [];
var num = 0;

function runQuery(term){

  for(var x=0; x<=3; x++){

  var URL = "https://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?
  publisher=4548xxxxxxxxxxxx&v=2&format=json&q=&l=" + term + "&radius=25&start=" + num + "
  &limit=25&latlong=1&co=us&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=GoogleChrome&v=2"

    return axios.get(URL).then(function(response) {

      for(var y=0; y<=response.data.results.length-1; y++){
          emptyArray.push(response.data.results[y]);
      }

      return emptyArray;

    }); //End axios.get

    num = num+25;

  }//End For Loop
} // End runQuery

runQuery("New York");
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think u just don't need the second for loop inside your callback, because your first loop already do the magic. It will trigger .get four times with 4 different callbacks. And use applyfunction to add response array to the existing one. Try to do it like this:

```
return axios.get(URL).then(function(response) {

      emptyArray.push.apply(emptyArray, response.data.results);

}); //End axios.get

num = num+25;
```